# Why is my web page stuck at the Pending status for over 30 seconds?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Ok, so I have a page... simple login page so there are no API calls or database hits on the initial load.

This is a .Net site on a new Azure app service. We have the page working well on other servers, but we just moved it to an app service for the first time and we are getting this weird behavior.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ywOp.png

You go to the page and it just sits there for 30 seconds or more. If you look at dev tools nothing is happening (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhoEp.png). Once the page is "found" everything loads quickly.

When I go to other pages, it is a similar story... wait forever, then everything loads in all at once.

Again, same code on a VM is zippy. Is there something I configured incorrectly on Azure? I have it "always on" so it doesn't sleep, but otherwise it is pretty standard.

**-- Update --**

Just answering the comments:

- @DA - The JS dependencies haven't changed and in the network tab I am not seeing any calls to 3rd parties.
- @Thiago - If there was a problem in startup, would it affect every page or just the initial load? I lean toward the initial load. Once it was done, then every other call should be fast right? That isn't what is happening here.

Comment: Do u have any JS dependencies that are from 3rd party providers? Maybe there is a latency between these providers and your new app service (because behind is also a VM).

Comment: seems to me you have some code in your startup.cs which is taking forever and hanging the first request

Comment: @DA Answered your questions above

Comment: Try to attach remote debugger from VS, put a break point and see what is going on
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/remote-debugging-azure-app-services/